# Android new version catalog dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio

How can add library from github?
examble:

```
dependencies {
 implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
}
```

also like this one

```
implementation 'com.github.dhimant1990:TimerTextView:v1.0'
```

New implement like this

```
implementation libs.appcompat
```

Comment: "What exactly do you want? 1. Adding an existing project to the version catalog. 2. Adding a new library to the version catalog system. "

Answer (score 0):

You can use jitpack.io for this, below implementation -

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ... other repositories

        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
   implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0'
   implementation 'com.github.dhimant1990:TimerTextView:v1.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
 implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.16.0")
 }
```

Right Click or alt+enter -> Replace with new new library CatLog declaration. Then you will see like that  implementation(libs.glide) and Sync Now